# Symfony 3 - Use session variables?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I would like to use session variables for my site.

I made :

```
$request = new Request();

    $session = $request->getSession();

    if ($session == null)
    {
        $session = new Session();
    }
$session->set('typeAuth','cas');
```

But in my controler, when I call this session variable by :

```
    $typeAuth = $_SESSION->get('typeAuth');
```

I've :

> Notice: Undefined variable: session

And I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly inject the `SessionInterface` in your constructor, then use it as property of your service.

In example :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface; // <--- use this namespace

class AuthCasService extends AuthAbstract implements AuthInterface {

    private $serializer;
    private $session;

    // Inject the SessionInterface ----------------------------------------------------------V-----------------------V
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, SerializerInterface $serializer, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    // Your methods ...
}
```

and then, in your method, remove `$session = $request->getSession();` and use `$this->session->set('foo', 'bar');`

Comment: Okay thanks ! And if I want to get a session variable from a controler ? I have to write a __construct() function ?
Moreover, using         $typeAuth = $_SESSION->get('typeAuth');
I've this error Error: Call to a member function get() on array

Comment: From a controller, you can use `$session = $request->getSession();`

Comment: `$_SESSION` is an array. `$typeauth = $_SESSION["typeAuth"];`